# vmware и конфигурация беспроводной сети

Tags: vmware

Имеется следующая конфигурация сети [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. На данном рисунке все компоненты это виртуальные машины:
Snort - ubuntu 14, user - ubuntu 14, victim - ubuntu 14, hacker - kali linux. Мне надо сделать, чтобы соединение между машинами snort и hacker было беспроводным. Подскажите как это можно осуществить. То есть я каким либо образом могу настроить машину snort, чтобы она выполняла роль роутера и позволяла соединяться с ней как через ethernet, так и через wireless соединения?

Comment: это виртуальные машины? причем тут vmware ?

Comment: ну меня интересует как в vmware настроить виртуальную машину snort, чтобы она wi-fi раздавала

Comment: у тебя wifi-адаптер должен быть на сервере вставлен, адаптер добавляешь в ESXi и вешаешь на виртуалку. Дльше настраиваешь внутри ОС раздачу по этому адаптеру

Comment: wifi-адаптер должен быть на сервере вставлен - имеется в виду на хост машине?

Comment: на физической машине, на котором крутится ESXi

Comment: ну хост машина. Ладно я Вас понял и туториалы находил для этого случая, но у меня комп подключен напрямую через кабель. Спасибо в любом случае за помощь)

Comment: можете ответ оформить, я вам плюсану

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на физической машине, на котором крутится ESXi, подключаете WiFi-адаптер.  адаптер добавляешь в ESXi(Settings -> Networking) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добвыляешь NIC-адаптер на витруальную машину и подключаешь к виртуальному свичу.

Дальше настраиваешь внутри ОС раздачу по этому адаптеру

Схема такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]